# How to insert data from text file into my table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have text files which contain one word per line, and I would like to add this content to a column in my table, the column type is Varchar, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Is there any specific technology you'd prefer to use? Anything you want to avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat your file as a special case of CSV - it's a CSV file with only one column.

See this [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) for how to bulk insert from a CSV file.

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use import wizard provided in the management studio. You can check this [link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm) for your reference.